# Execute Batch file in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to execute a `.bat` file from a Windows Subsystem for Linux (eg. Ubuntu)?

It is trivial to run an `.exe` file from a WSL, but I haven't found a trivial way to run a `.bat`. The only way I found is to open `cmd.exe`, but that is a bit cumbersome to do every time I need to execute a `.bat` file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment you cannot do so without either using:

```bash
cmd.exe /c foo.bat
```

…or the following hack using binfmt:

```bash
sudo sh -c "echo :WindowsBatch:E::bat::/init: > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register"
```

You could then just type:

```bash
foo.bat
```

*The problems with this method are that you'd need to be root, run it each time you opened a bash window, probably do the same for `.cmd` files too and, I suppose, any bash script name ending with `.bat` could have issues!*

I guess until Microsoft deals with this issue, you're limited to the above.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I was afraid this was the case. At least the `cmd.exe /c foo.bat` command is good enough for me now.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I needed this to launch `gradlew.bat` in the terminal in Android Studio so I created an alias in my `~/.bashrc`: `alias gradlewin='cmd.exe /c gradlew.bat`'.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to post on such an old thread but I found a way around it (not sure if it's something that's changed from updates, I'm posting on 18/02/2021).  I found that running CMD and then feeding it arguments (to link to the requisite batch file) works - it also an accept constructed arguments sent to that command.  So in my case (I'm using Debian 10.8 in WSL on 10 Pro):

```sh
/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /mnt/c/temp/batchfile.bat "-arga -argb -argc"
```

I think this may be fairly consistent and workable workaround (just using `C:\temp\bathfile.bat` as an example, just use the relative `/mnt/<drv>/<dir>/<batchfile>` path for your needs).

Comment: I'm using windows 11 21H2 , ```/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /mnt/c/temp/batchfile.bat``` is worked for me :)

Comment: When I try to do this it just opens cmd in the terminal in my current directory. It is not executing the batch file which I supplied

Comment: I had to do this:
`/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c C:\\temp\\batchfile.bat`

Comment: Thank you @BenR, `/c` was the tweak I needed. It even read the path and didn't need the full path to the batch file.

`/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c avdmanager.bat`

Answer (score 3):

If the first answer doesn't work, try:

```
sudo sh -c "echo :WindowsBatch:E::bat::/init: > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register"
```

Then, locate the file. Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x foo.bat
```

Then run the file:

```
./foo.bat
```

If it says permission denied, just try running it with sudo